# pymssql.connect() seems to ignore database string argument

Tags: python, sql, azure, pymssql

I have 3 dbs in Azure which I tried connecting to one of them.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server='hostname.database.windows.net',
                  user='username@hostname',
                  password='*****',
                  database='my_db',
                  timeout=0,
                  login_timeout=60,
                  charset='UTF-8',
                  as_dict=False,
                  host='',
                  port='1433')


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select db_name()')  #to get the name of my db (which should be "my_db")
result = cursor.fetchone()
print result
```

But what I've got is "master" which is default Azure database. This shouldn't happen because I've already specify 'databse' string argument to "my_db".

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your version of `pymssql`. 
The latest version on `pip` is `2.1.0`, but the version that supports `azure` is 2.1.1.
So, if you install it from source, it will work. Also, make sure you have `freeTDS` > 0.91

Comment: You may want to elaborate on why `freeTDS` is an additional requirement. Otherwise, welcome to SO

Comment: [tag:pymssql] is a python interface to [tag:freeTDS].